# Can I add a link to developers that I have worked with in real life?

Tags: feature-request

There are a number of Stack Overflow (+SF,SU, and Meta) users at my company and at my school that I know personally. I think it would be a useful feature to be able to have other users' flair on a tab in my account, that way I could check out what they've been asking/answering recently. Sure, I can use the users tab, and I can understand why "friending" hasn't been implemented, but I think a simple flair page could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site is not meant to be a social networking site.  The creator (Jeff) has turned down every feature request like this for that reason.

However, I would be interested in some social networking aspects for the site.

Comment: Perfect answer. When do you want to get started on building a developer network based off the SO engine?

Comment: Well, if you have a business proposition my profile contains information on how to contact me. `:P`

Answer (score 6):

You could host this easily enough yourself, create your own html page with a "wall" of your friends flair links. You could set it as your homepage so you check em out every time you start browsing.
Simply change the userid for each of your friends

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/**99999**.html

You can also then easily set up to view their flair from all sites

This should do it for you, for a sense of scale you could include Jon Skeet :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>SO Sites Flair</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="subheader">
        <h1>SO Sites Flair</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content-page">
        <h2>
            How am I doing today?</h2>
        <p>

            <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="210px" height="60px" src="http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1.html">
            </iframe>
            <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="210px" height="60px" src="http://serverfault.com/users/flair/1.html">
            </iframe>
            <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="210px" height="60px" src="http://superuser.com/users/flair/1.html">
            </iframe>
            <iframe marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="210px" height="60px" src="https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/1.html">
            </iframe>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate this post quite a bit actually, as I was just working on doing this. However, the basis was more about Meta itself, and it seems that the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

Just link to their profiles in your bio, if you want it public.

Otherwise, use your browser's "bookmark" feature...