# Social following based on tag badges as a low-effort alternative to social-network style following

Tags: feature-request, question-quality, social-networking

I pose this question only as an alternative to Pekka's [suggestion for user following](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-user). I like the idea of providing more value for users with expertise.

As mentioned in my answer to his question, I was concerned that following other users required extra effort to decide who was worth following, and that "recommending" questions would create a parallel system to upvoting, for not much payoff. Completely spontaneously, I thought of an alternative that would leverage the existing SO/SE infrastructure.

The principle of my suggestion is: **Rather than following individual users, "follow" the group of users with expertise in the tags you are interested in, as determined by their possession of a tag-badge for that tag.**

As mentioned in my answer to the other post, the idea would be that when you choose to follow a tag, you would be presented with an interface at bit like this:

---

[checkbox] Highlight questions upvoted by users with this tag badge
[checkbox] Highlight questions favorited by users with this tag badge
[checkbox] Highlight questions commented on by users with this tag badge (*added*)
[checkbox] Highlight questions answered by users with this tag badge (*added*)

- [radio button] Include only questions tagged [text box - the followed tag would be included by default]
- [radio button - default] Exclude questions tagged [text box]

---

A similar interface could be shown in the margins of the question list when you filter it for a particular tag, as an additional filter.

The advantages of this proposal are:

- Users don't need to do anything more than what they are currently doing
- Users don't need to work out for themselves who the real experts are, or "maintain" their own expert list
- It distinguishes between expert answerers and frequent askers
- It provides regular and expert users with a way to "up-weight" the opinions of other expert users, without being drowned in the upvotes on questions subject to the "bike shed effect"
- It does not require any new attributes in the database, such as recommendations on posts, or number of followers on users
- It allows for some serendipity, e.g. seeing what [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) questions the [php](/questions/tagged/php) experts think are interesting.
- It provides for some of the information-sharing aspects of [clan/team affiliation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8068/add-clan-or-team-affiliation-support) based on tag badges, without creating much of the incentive to game the rep system the way a clan/team system would.

I hope this proposal satisfies some of the appetite for "social-ness" without losing sight of what SE sites are meant to be about.

Comment: "appetite for social-ness"? I thought this was a site for programmers.

Comment: :-D Mathematica programmers are reasonably social

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting idea, but as pointed out in the comments to [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-user/106748#106748), I have serious doubts about whether those factors can reliably point to a high-quality, interesting question. Still, it might work.

> [checkbox] Highlight questions upvoted by users with this tag badge

This is the most likely candidate for finding good content; however, I tend to upvote well-put, well-researched questions even if they are on extremely basic topics. If that is common, voting behaviour would not be a good indicator for expert, interesting content.

> [checkbox] Highlight questions favorited by users with this tag badge

My initial idea was using this. However, favouriting questions has many uses in the system - as a bookmarking tool for any reason, whether the question is interesting or not. Still, this could work.

> [checkbox] Highlight questions commented on by users with this tag badge (added)

Absolutely not. A huge portion of comments is made because a question is bad, or something is blatantly wrong. Commenting activity is **not** a good indicator of good content.

> [checkbox] Highlight questions answered by users with this tag badge (added)

My argument against this one is that if a user I trust has already answered this, chances are there's nothing left for me to do. Also, answering is not *necessarily* a good indicator of an interesting question.  Example from a moment ago:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483090/javascript-path-not-working-in-ubentu-windows-it-works

Overall -  I'm mixed about this. I would favour an explicit system with recommendations, but an automated mixture of some factors (except comments. Please, except comments) could help find good content as well.

A combination of upvoting and favouriting from an at least bronze-badge user could deliver good results. It might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks, the comment and answer elements were additions in response to Jeff's answer on yours. I'd gladly roll back that edit.